# Another Token error: EOF in multi-line statement

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, easygui

**The following code gives me this error "Token Error: EOF in multi-line statement". I cannot seem to find the error though! Maybe someone else will see it?**

```
import easygui
import time
namegui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter your name:', title='Name query', default='Gian')
situationgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter your situation:', title='Thought Log(Situation)')
thoughtsgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter your thoughts:', title='Thought Log(Thoughts')
emotionsgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter your emotions: \n Sad, Mad, Hurt, Depressed, Anxious, Tense, etc.', title='Thought Log(Emotions')
behaviorgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter your behavior:', title='Thought Log(Behavior')


#thinking_trapsgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please identify your thinking traps: \n \n'
#    'FORTUNE-TELLING: This occurs when we predict that things will turn out badly. However, we cannot predict the future because we do not have a magic ball! \n \n'
#    'MIND-READING: This happens when we believe that we know what others are thinking and we assume that they are thinking the worst of us. However, we cannot mind-read so we do not know what others are thinking! \n \n'
#    'LABELING: Sometimes we talk to ourselves in a mean way and we use a single negative word to describe ourselves. However, this kind of thinking is unfair and we are too complex to be summed up in a single word! \n \n'
#    'FILTERING: This happens when we take note of all the bad things that happen, but ignore any good things. \n \n'
#    'OVERESTIMATING: This happens when we believe that something that is unlikely to occur is actually about to happen. \n \n'
#    'CATASTROPHIZING: This is when we imagine the worst possible thing is about to happen and we will be unable to cope with it. \n \n'
#    'OVERGENERALIZING: This is when we use words like always or never to describe situations or events. This is a problematic way of thinking because it does not take all situation or events into account \n \n',
#    title='Thought Log(Identify Your Thinking Traps)')

thinking_trapsgui = easygui.choicebox(
    msg='Please identify your thinking traps: \n \n',
    title='Thought Log(Identify Your Thinking Traps)',
    choices=('FORTUNE-TELLING: This occurs when we predict that things will turn out badly. However, we cannot predict the future because we do not have a magic ball! \n \n'
             'MIND-READING: This happens when we believe that we know what others are thinking and we assume that they are thinking the worst of us. However, we cannot mind-read so we do not know what others are thinking! \n \n'
             'LABELING: Sometimes we talk to ourselves in a mean way and we use a single negative word to describe ourselves. However, this kind of thinking is unfair and we are too complex to be summed up in a single word! \n \n'
             'FILTERING: This happens when we take note of all the bad things that happen, but ignore any good things. \n \n'
             'OVERESTIMATING: This happens when we believe that something that is unlikely to occur is actually about to happen. \n \n'
             'CATASTROPHIZING: This is when we imagine the worst possible thing is about to happen and we will be unable to cope with it. \n \n'
             'OVERGENERALIZING: This is when we use words like always or never to describe situations or events. This is a problematic way of thinking because it does not take all situation or events into account \n \n'
             )


alt_behaviorgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter alternative behavior:', title='Thought Log(Alt Behavior)')
alt_thoughtsgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter alternative thoughts:', title='Thought Log(Alt Thoughts)')
yeargui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current year:', title='Current Year', default='2011')
monthgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current month:', title='Current Month')
daygui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current day:', title='Current Day')
time_hourgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Enter the current hour:', title='Current Hour')
time_minutegui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter current minutes:', title='Current Minute')
am_pmgui = easygui.enterbox(msg='Please enter either am or pm:', title='AM OR PM')
file = open('Thought Record 1.0.txt', 'a')
file.write(namegui + '\n')
file.write(daygui)
file.write('/')
file.write(monthgui)
file.write('/')
file.write(yeargui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your situation:')
file.write(situationgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your thoughts:')
file.write(thoughtsgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your emotions:')
file.write(emotionsgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your behavior:')
file.write(behaviorgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Thinking traps:')
file.write(thinking_trapsgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Alternative bahvior:')
file.write(alt_behaviorgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Alternative thoughts:')
file.write(alt_thoughtsgui)
file.write('\n')
file.write('\n')
file.close()
```

Also the error always highlights the last line after `file.close()`. I do not understand why?

**I am running Python 2.5 on Mac OS X 10.6**

Comment: There's too much extraneous code. Please reduce it to a [minimal sample](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you Outis :-) This is very insightful.

Comment: If you use an editor with syntax highlighting (vim, emacs, visual studio, several others) these types of errors are trivial to spot. Consider switching to a better editor

Comment: Thank you Bryan Oakley. I am looking into an IDE named Aptana. It is based on Eclipse and comes with Pydev built in.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing ) for variable thinking_trapsgui. Check if thats the problem.

A missing ) usually gives a Syntax Error so I am not really sure, but EOF multi-line Token Error could be pointing to that.

EDIT

You have written

```
thinking_trapsgui = easygui.choicebox(
    msg='Please identify your thinking traps: \n \n',
    title='Thought Log(Identify Your Thinking Traps)',
    choices=('FORTUNE-TELLING: This occurs when we predict that things will turn out badly. However, we cannot predict the future because we do not have a magic ball! \n \n'
         'MIND-READING: This happens when we believe that we know what others are thinking and we assume that they are thinking the worst of us. However, we cannot mind-read so we do not know what others are thinking! \n \n'
         'LABELING: Sometimes we talk to ourselves in a mean way and we use a single negative word to describe ourselves. However, this kind of thinking is unfair and we are too complex to be summed up in a single word! \n \n'
         'FILTERING: This happens when we take note of all the bad things that happen, but ignore any good things. \n \n'
         'OVERESTIMATING: This happens when we believe that something that is unlikely to occur is actually about to happen. \n \n'
         'CATASTROPHIZING: This is when we imagine the worst possible thing is about to happen and we will be unable to cope with it. \n \n'
         'OVERGENERALIZING: This is when we use words like always or never to describe situations or events. This is a problematic way of thinking because it does not take all situation or events into account \n \n'
         )
```

The last ')' above is for chioces argument. So just add another ')' at the end of the above line.

Comment: Would you please show me how the code would look with the missing )? I do not see what you are talking about. There is a ) at the end of thinking_trapsgui.

Comment: You need two `)` at the end of the said line: one for `thinking_trapsgui`, and one for its argument `choices`!